# How can I make an icon appear next to my title in the <title> tag?

Tags: html

In my website, I want a small icon next to the title of my webpage. ***I do mean the one displayed on the tab in Chrome/IE/Firefox.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/logo1.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Note: Generally try to use ico file(recommended). You can use a tool to convert your LOGO to an ico file. There are many available on google.

Comment: I used a normal JPG and it worked fine, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yea you can use any image type. Its just a recommendation for good website building

Comment: type attribute should contain valid mime type. "images/icon" is invalid. "image/png" will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as,

```
<head>
  <title>This is the title of my website.</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

[Read this link](http://www.metatags.org/design_tips_favicon_ico)

If your `website` doesn't have this `icon` you will get an error on every visited web page.
This `favicon.ico` must be `16 by 16 pixels`. If it's larger or smaller, it will be ignored 
and it won't be shown. You can create this icon by using a icon editor with an `online generator` or just by using `Photoshop`.

[Online ico generator](http://www.icoconverter.com/)

Comment: Wasn't me, but:
* Nowadays, favicons can be up to 32px²
* If the file is not found, it pretty much depends on the browser: Firefox ignores, IE shows a blank sheet icon, etc
* Technically it can be any image format (with the correct MIME), but `.ico` is just a recommended standard. All major browsers support GIF, JPG and PNG (at least).